# Edit DataTable cell

Tags: c#, datatable

I would like to edit cells in columns in my DataTable I have

```
DataTable theDataTable = new DataTable();
theDataTable.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
theDataTable.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
theDataTable.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(string));
```

It gets it data from a text file so it looks like this

```
Column1    Column2    Column3
2015-03-23 T_Someinfo 040-555555
2015-03-24 T_Someinfo 040-666666
2015-03-23 T_Someinfo 040-666666
```

Now I want to search for '-' in Column3 and remove it.
So the result in Column3 will look like this.

```
Column3
040555555
040666666
040666666
```

How can I search for '-' and remove it from the cell in a DataTable?

Comment: Iterate through `Rows` and modify each cell, have you tried anything ?

Comment: _"It gets it data from a text file so it looks like this"_ Then change the code which loads the `DataTable` from the text-file instead of fixing the table afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate throw `Rows` and modify each cell like:

```
foreach (DataRow row in theDataTable.Rows)
{
    if (row["Column3"] != null)
        row["Column3"] = row["Column3"].ToString().Replace("-", "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
// We iterate through the DataTable rows.
foreach(DataRow row in theDataTable .Rows)
{
    // We get the value of Column3 for the current row and replace 
    // the - with empty.
    string value = row.Field<string>("Column3").Replace("-","");

    // Then we update the value.
    row.SetField("Column3", value);
}
```